# Lock Free: Spilitting compound, non-atomic operation into simpler atomic operations

Tags: java, multithreading, lock-free, atomic

I am writing a financial market data distributor application as part of my M.S project. The application is almost finished but the app is not scaling well.

This is how it works, I subscribe to a "fake" exchange to get market data.
After subscribing, I get an initial snapshot and then I receive deltas continously ...

```
1) Subscribe for IBM.
2) Snapshot : Buy:50|Size:1400||Sell:49|Size:1000
(At buy price of 50, 1400 shares and at sell price of 49, 1000 shares available)
3) Update1: -1|10||-2|25
(Buy price is now 49 (50-1), buy Size is 1410. Sell price is 47 and sell size is 1025)
4) Update2 ...
.
.
.
```

I have one class that processes the market data, the dataUpdate() below is a callback method which the "fake" exchange application calls in one thread.

```
class MarketDataProcessor:
Map<String, MarketData> marketDataMap      = new HashMap<String, MarketData>(1000);
ConcurrentMap<String, MarketData> distMap  = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, MarketData>();

//**Always called by one thread (MarketDataThread)**
    public void dataUpdate( MarketDataUpdate dataUpdate ){

            try{
                 //IBM
                 String symbol   = dataUpdate .getSymbol();             
                 MarketData data = marketDataMap.get( symbol );

                 if ( data = null ){
                    data = new MarketData( dataUpdate );
                 }else{
                    //Apply the delta here and save it ...
                    marketDataMap.put( symbol, data );
                 }

                 distMap.put( symbol, data );

            }catch( Exception e ){
               LOGGER.warn("Exception while processing market data.");
               LOGGER.warn("Exception: {}", e);
            }
    }
```

After getting market data from the exchange, I need to distribute it in a thread safe manner. **This is the method that doesnt scale well as it could be called by 20+ threads and it uses an external lock to ensure atomicity.**

```
public final double[] getData( String symbol, Side side ){
     double[] dataArray = {0.0, 0.0};

     synchronized( LOCK ){
        MarketData data = distMap.get( symbol );
        dataArray       = ( side == BUY ) ? getBuyData(data) : getSellData(data); 
     }

  return dataArray;
}
```

**Here is my proposed solution is to split the above method into two.**

```
//No external lock as it uses a ConcurrentHashMap
public final MarketData getData( String symbol ){
       return distMap.get( symbol );
}

//State of this method is now confimed to the
//stack of the calling thread, therefore thread safe.
public final double[] getData( MarketData data, Side side ){
       return ( side == BUY ) ? getBuyData(data) : getSellData(data); 
}
```

Conceding that this will change the api and make the users call two methods than one, does it not make it thread-safe without using an external lock?

Thank you.

Comment: Just an idea - have you considered something like: (i) a MarketDataProvider that gets the market quotes from a queue for example (ii) External clients that can subscribe to the MarketDataProvider with a subscribe method to let the MarketDataProvider know which securities / events they are interested in (iii) when a new data is captured by the MarketDataProvider, it iterates over the subscribers to push the new data to those interested.

Comment: @assylias - Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, as decided by the creators of the project, I have to provide a "pull" mechanism for distributing data.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a great idea to have many threads dumping into a single synchronized thread that takes time.

Could you dump those results into a synchronized queue to be analyzed later?  A single thread can pull items out of the queue while many threads put it in.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Bill - the synchronized method getData(...) is used by multiple threads to pull data. Putting the data in a synchronized queue would work but I dont think it will eliminate locking (it will just be delegated to the queue from the method ). I am hoping to remove synchronization alltogether from the getData() method.

Comment: If you have to combine data from different threads there has to be some synchronization--the trick is to minimalize the time spent in the synchronous block.  Or perhaps I don't fully understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

First, I have no idea what is the resources that your LOCK is controlling accessing.  Which part of your code is unsafe and why you think using the LOCK there is helping?  Your new methods are also not providing same signature as your original one.  Do you expect people to use it like

```
getData(getData(symbol), side)
```

?

if the original code without lock is not thread safe, your new way has nothing different from that.

Go back to your original implementation: The only resources you are accessing in the LOCK-protected piece of code is distMap.  No other place is using the LOCK.  Therefore what you are doing here is you want only 1 thread to ***get*** data from distMap.  However I don't see rationale for that: First distMap is a ConcurrentMap, it is thread safe to be accessed by multiple thread.  Second, for every kind of Map, simply getting data is always thread safe, because no one is changing the state.  Normally what you need to perform synchronization control should include the state-changing logic, which is where you put data in the map (though in this specific piece of code, there is no reason adding extra synchronization control), but you are not doing so.  I simply cannot understand the whole purpose for your LOCK.

Some comments to you: simply blindly using synchronized/LOCK etc is not changing your code automatically to thread-safe.  You need to know what is not thread-safe and do your synchronization control accordingly.  Another comment is: breaking a non-atomic method into atomic piece is NOT going to make your code thread-safe.  Just think in another way: almost all lowest level action in Java is atomic.  Does that mean your code is automatically thread safe because you are calling a bunch of atomic actions?  Obviously not.

Comment: Thanks for the comments; the LOCK, in my case, exists to ensure atomicity.   The compound ops of looking up the data in the map and performing getBuyData(...)/getSellData(...) has to be atomic otherwise there is a possibility of data race.  Yes, as you mention, the api changes after the split.  "Second, for every kind of Map, simply getting data is always thread safe, because no one is changing the state." - I disagree, there will be "visibility" issues, data added by one thread will not be visible to another thread. ( http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/jmm.html)

Comment: @CaptainHastings First, tell me how that can cause any race condition in your new code if there is no LOCK, and how it can be solved by your new approach.  For visibility issue, what you said is correct BUT that's why I said "simply getting data".  If no one is changing the state, simply tons of thread reading the map, is not going to cause thread-safety issue.  Your so-called "atomicity" is simply dealing with this case.  If you are concerning about visibility (and other thread safety issue), you should have included the map update in synchonrization control

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers provide good advise, there is another option available that is lock free: use a persistent map (like from pcollections). The reader threads would always have a consistent snapshot of the data; the writer thread would be creating creating new versions of the map-but without copying all the data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I found Cliff Click's NonBlockingHashMap which could replace the ConcurrentHashMap. I will need to create some test classes to figure out the pros/cons of each under varing loads... Cheers.

Comment: Concurrent and persistent data-structures are very different things. Concurrent data-structures allow concurrent updates to the same instance; persistent data-structures efficiently create *new* instances. Persistent data-structures are widely used by functional languages; no need to lock because the data-structures are immutable

Comment: Oh I see, sorry, I didn't know about pcollections (although I have seen cases where immutable objects are heavily favored over synchronization + updating state of mutable objects). I will give it a look. Thanks.